# Air flow rate through thin pipe from a tank

Tags: pressure, airflow, compressible-flow

I would like to study the air pressure in a rigid box. One side of the box can be moved like a piston, so I can change its volume, which results in pressure change inside the box. Morover I installed a little pipe into the box, which connects the air inside to the outside. This pipe has a certain length and a certain radius. I used the following equations to simulate the system:
$$
p(t)=\frac{m(t)RT}{V(t)}
$$
$$
V(t)=V_0+x(t)\cdot A
$$
$$
m(t)=m_0+\int_0^tQ_m(t)dt
$$
$$
Q_m(t)=\frac{\rho(t)\pi r^4}{16\mu L}\cdot \frac{p(t)^2-p_0^2}{p_0}
$$
$$
\rho(t)=\frac{m(t)}{V(t)}
$$
Here the parameters:

$p_0$: the initial pressure both inside and outside, $p(t)$: pressure inside the box, $m_0$: initial air mass inside the box, $m(t)$: air mass inside the box, $V_0$: the initial volume of the box $V(t)$: volume of the box, $R$=287, $T$=293.15, $x(t)$: the displacement of the movable part of the box, $A$: the area of the moveable part of the box, $Q_m(t)$: the mass flow rate through the orifice pipe, $\rho(t)$: the density of air inside the box, $r$: the radius of the pipe, $L$: the length of the pipe, $\mu$: the air voscosity.
My question: is this make sense? Is it a good approach of the problem? Edit: I found, the mass flow rate I used is called Hagen–Poiseuille equation, and it is for slow, voscous, laminar flow, so maybe it is not suited to this scenario. I have found another approach, the orifice plate, but that is a thin plate, and I want to work with a pipe which has length.